# How to mix the data of two tables with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hello I'm learning how to use MySQL and Node JS and I'm trying to find a query to mix two tables. If I got a table "users" with the columns "userId", "userImage" and another table "comments" with the columns "commentId", "comment", "commentUserId", "threadId". Do you know if I can add the images of the users who commented in the results of this query please ?

`'SELECT * FROM comments where threadId = ?'`

Comment: That is a simple join. Please take a SQL tutorial first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use **SQL joins** to make that.

Here you have examples of SQL Joins :
[SQL JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

In your case, you can make a query as the following :

```
SELECT users.userImage, comments.commentId [ you select what you need in here ]
FROM comments
INNER JOIN users ON comments.commentUserId = users.userId
where threadId = ? ;
```